# Firefox problem with long running PHP script

Tags: php, firefox, optimization

I have a PHP script that takes 2 or 3 minutes to complete. I have a mail() call at the end of the script and I receive the mail correctly but Firefox still just sits there saying "Loading..." even though I know the script has finished because I've had the mail.

I have important debug info that I echo or print_r to the screen but I'm not seeing these debugs due to the browser problem.

Anyone experienced this before? Know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: u need to optimize your code...paste your code on `codepad.org`

Comment: I have PHP scripts that takes ~87 years to complete... but no one can help me without code or examples. Update your question, please, with relevant code (I actually have that script) :)

Comment: Both, I think you have misread / misunderstood my problem. Why would it be my code? the code is completing correctly and as expected within 2 or 3 minutes. It's just the browser doesn't seem to recognise that script has finished. Thanks for taking the time to reply though.

Comment: than, it's something wrong with Firefox but I can't tell you what exactly. Hope anybody here may help on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Fiddler Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

> Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which
>   logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your
>   computer and the Internet. Fiddler
>   allows you to inspect all HTTP(S)
>   traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle"
>   with incoming or outgoing data.
>   Fiddler includes a powerful
>   event-based scripting subsystem, and
>   can be extended using any .NET
>   language.
>
> Fiddler is freeware and can debug
>   traffic from virtually any
>   application, including Internet
>   Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, and
>   thousands more.

Fiddler can let you know what is happening behind the scenes that is delaying the browser after your mail has been sent.

Comment: Thanks Cogicero. I'll look in to Fiddler!